# Create XML with parent and child element

Tags: sql

I have to create an XML file with the below format.
*office_tel* and *mobile* are fields of a table.
Any help would be valuable.

```
 <fields>
   <office_tel>
     <value>1234</value>
   </office_tel>
   <mobile>
     <value>99999</value>
   </mobile>
</fields>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow... it' unclear what exactly you need from us. Can you give us more information  about what you've tried and why that was unsatisfactory to you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `SQL SERVER`. Ref [FOR XML (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178107.aspx)

```
SELECT 
   office_tel as "office_tel/value",
   mobile as "mobile/value"
FROM TableName
FOR XML PATH('fields')
```